# Children.Add() in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

im really new to c# and Xamarin Forms but can someone please explain to me why I'm getting an error in the last line of code below ?

Visual Studio is indicating a curly red underline on the word `Children` on the last line of this code indicating that there is some syntax error but I don't see why that is an error since I'm just accessing a member of the class ....

```
var content = new ContentPage();
content.Title = "Appuler";

Label CompanyName = new Label();
CompanyName.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
CompanyName.Text = "Test";

Button NextPage = new Button();
NextPage.Text = "Next Page";
NextPage.Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large);
NextPage.BorderWidth = 1;
NextPage.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
NextPage.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;

content.Content = new StackLayout();
content.Content.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
content.Content.Children.Add(CompanyName);
```

Comment: What is the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor the last few lines to the following

```
var layout = new StackLayout();
layout.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
layout.Children.Add(CompanyName);
content.Content = layout;
```

[ContentPage.Content](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage.Content/) does not have that `Children` property as it is a `View`. `StackLayout`, however does have a `Children` property that can be accessed.

populate the layout control's accessible properties and then assign it to the `Content` property of the `ContentPage`.

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal the `Content` property is a `View` while `StackLayout` is derived from `View`. `View` would not have all the properties that `StackLayout` has hence the error.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Thats why I can do the second last line and not the last line. Because as you said, View would not have all the properties of a StackLayout. Thanks for the help man, much appreciated. Merry Xmas!